# What is the benefit of the Digital NOTAM over the conventional ICAO NOTAM?

Tags: notam, aeronautical-information, aim

Us I understand it the Digital NOTAM (AIXM 5.1 Event Specification) does allow coding the events (deviation from normal operation) in a more structured form.
That allows the user to:

1. Link the Event implicitly to an (one or more) AIXM 5.1 Feature
2. Provide the information in the structured XML (AIXM 5.1) format allowing better machine processing capabilities (schema validation, filtering, sorting, ...)

Is there any other benefit?
For 1) I do see the problem, that if the Digital NOTAM is shared, the linkage is only based on UUIDs -> but if the other party is  not having the very same Static Data baseline, the UUID will not help (some kind of Natural Keys would be needed).

I miss the advantage, that I could "apply" the changes directly to the Static Data (as it is AIXM 5.1) but it seems this is not foreseen, and I would consider this as a big lacking functionality.

Further, I do ask myself how the exchange of the Digital NOTAM is envisioned to be done.

Currently the exchange of NOTAM is done as I see it in the following ways:
a) World Exchange via AFTN, where "all" NOTAM can be published (and therefore retrieved)
b) via "property" interfaces (based on open standards).

With Digital NOTAM I do not see the AFTN working any more - how should this work in the future.